# Deployment of Python app to AWS

Tags: python, git, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As some of my projects are getting complicated and involve more work needed to actually deploy the application to the server, I wanted to ask for your help since I haven't had a lot of experience with this.

At the moment I have one app written in Flask, using MySQL as a backend, Apache with mod_wsgi, which is available at single EC2 instance. Now, things are about to get slightly more complicated, as I will have another "cloned" version of the application, on a different domain, with new templates, language and some minor differences, but the core code would be the same. I also have some sort of "demo" site, which is available at domain.com/demo, handled by different app since its functionality is kinda limited so its different from the  main version.

My deployment practice now, since this is relatively simple, to just `wget` the files from my Dropbox to the EC2 instance (I ssh in) and restart the apache service. As I have app code in a single file, and templates directory, and some other smaller scripts which are not updated often, this wasn't an issue. When I change code, I just get the source updated, and when I changed the templates, zip em, wget, unzip and that's it.

This was how I managed to do things so far. I recently started using GitHub as well for versioning, and would like some advice for my following concern:

- Which would be the best way to automate this process? I suppose that prefered way is to pull things from the git repository upon each commit and deploy it on the EC2 instance. If this is the case, how can I automate this? Github hooks seem like a bit of an overkill, I hope there is "simpler" tool for this. Maybe beanstalk offered by Amazon can jump in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, put all your commands in a [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) script, it will make things easier in the long run.

You have a asked a very broad question with lots of opportunity for subjective answers, for which I had to vote to close it.  There are lots of good parts to your question which is why I try to provide some answer.

1. There is no preferred way.  Do you want to install git as a dependency on your production/staging/web machines? If you want to, deploying with git is perfectly acceptable, if not it is just as easy to use built in `rsync` utility and interact with it using fabric.  There are lots of scripts online showing how to set up fabric using either way.  There are probably a number of other ways too but rsync or git pull seems to be the most popular ways to deploy.
2. Fabric lets you define [roles](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.roles), and makes it easy to deploy to multiple servers at one time.
3. Special cases require special functions.  You can define these in your fab file. You could create the logic to deploy to your general web servers in a function then have a seperate function to build and deploy your fragmented server.
4. Amazon provides a couple of autoscaling tools, I have never used any but I am sure that lots of people have, and lots of people have blogged about their experiences.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have tried fabric and created a nice tool that now commit changes, pushes it to github, and deploys it to the remote server. I realize my question is too broad, I will try to edit it and be more specific in the future.